# How to disable Emacs+AUCTex formating for a particular chapter

Tags: emacs, auctex

Emacs+AUCTeX formats automatically the titles (section, part, ...) by increasing the font and changing the color.

I would like to disable this behavior for one (and only one) chapter. This chapter is used to print the name of the (mini) table of contents and I don't want it to be emphasized.

Comment: The only way I can think to do this is to externalize it to another file with `\input` and disable the section fontification for the file.

Comment: ...makes sense what @SeanAllred, especially since it's only one chapter, altthough I would just use a part or section instead of chapter, withtin the same file, ....`customize variable font latex deactivated keyword classes` and append a check mark to teh sectioning-face itself...